# Implementing Down and Up (semaphore) with XCGH instruction

Tags: assembly, semaphore

The function to lock a mutex can be written in assembly language with the XCHG instruction like this:

```
mutex_lock:
    MOVE REGISTRO,#1    
    XCHG REGISTRO,MUTEX  
    CMP REGISTRO,#0     
    JZE ok          
    CALL thread_yield   
    JMP mutex_lock      
ok: RET          

mutex_unlock:
    MOVE MUTEX,#0       
    RET
```

¿Is there any way to write in assembly language the function to Up and the function to Down a semaphore with the XCHG instruction?

Comment: Sure, use the mutex to guard the semaphore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use the `CMPXCHG` instruction. This instruction basically combines a comparison and exchange in a single operation. It compares the source operand with the destination operand, setting the flags accordingly. Then, if they are equal (ZF == 1), it copies the value from the source into the destination. Otherwise (ZF == 0), it leaves the destination alone. Combined with a `LOCK` prefix, this is handy for atomic operations in a multithreaded environment, because it allows you to safely update a value stored in shared memory.

The only caveat to `CMPXCHG` is that it requires a Pentium or later processor. Today, this is obviously not a problem, but if you're doing retro-programming, you might need to look elsewhere. (Of course, retro-programmers don't really have to worry about multiple processors, and often don't even have multiple threads.)

Here is a sample implementation for a binary semaphore, written in a pseudo-MASM-style syntax. A binary semaphore is one whose value is either 0 (unlocked) or 1 (locked).

```
; This function attempts to obtain the semaphore.
;
; It compares the current value of the semaphore to 0. If it is 0, that means
; the semaphore is not currently locked (i.e., it is available), so this function
; sets it to 1, thus marking it as locked. Otherwise, if the semaphore is already locked,
; this function blocks (waits indefinitely) until it becomes available,
; and then locks it as described above.
;
; The address of the semaphore flag to lock is passed on the stack.
; It is the caller's responsibility to clean the stack (__cdecl).
; 
; Clobbers: EAX, EDX
Lock PROC
    mov  edx, DWORD PTR [esp + 4] ; get address of semaphore (passed as sole parameter on stack)

  WaitUntilAvailable:
    mov  eax, 1
    lock cmpxchg DWORD PTR [edx], eax
    jz   Finished
    ; TODO: Add code to suspend the thread (yield execution) while waiting,
    ;       for example by calling the Win32 Sleep function.
    ;       Currently, this just spins a busy loop.
    jmp  WaitUntilAvailable

  Finished:
    ret
Lock ENDP


; This function releases the semaphore.
; 
; If the semaphore is currently locked (has a value of 1), it is reset to 0.
; 
; The address of the semaphore flag to lock is passed on the stack.
; It is the caller's responsibility to clean the stack (__cdecl).
; 
; Clobbers: EAX, EDX
Unlock PROC
    mov  edx, DWORD PTR [esp + 4]
    xor  eax, eax
    lock cmpxchg DWORD PTR [edx], eax
    ret
Unlock ENDP
```

You could easily modify these to work for a counting semaphore, if you wanted. In this case, since you want to actually increment/decrement the value, you could use the `XADD` instruction. I know for a fact that this is supported on the 486 and later, plus it is considerably faster than `CMPXCHG`. Here's a sketch of what the code might look like:

```
; Waits for a semaphore to become available.
; 
; If the value of the semaphore variable is non-zero, decrement it by 1 and return.
; Otherwise, block execution until the semaphore's value is greater than
; or equal to 1 (i.e., add the caller to the semaphore's queue and wait
; until it becomes available).
; 
; Clobbers: EAX, EDX
SemaphoreWait PROC
    mov  edx, DWORD PTR [esp + 4]
    jmp  Check

  WaitUntilAvailable:
    pause   ; (or some other way to yield)

  Check:
    mov  eax, DWORD PTR [edx]
    test eax, eax
    jle  Check
    mov  eax, -1
    lock xadd DWORD PTR [edx], eax
    test eax, eax
    jg   Finished
    lock inc DWORD PTR [edx]
    jmp  WaitUntilAvailable

  Finished:
    ret
SemaphoreWait ENDP


; Signals (releases) a semaphore, incrementing its value by 1.
; 
; Clobbers: EAX
SemaphoreSignal PROC
    mov  eax, DWORD PTR [esp + 4]
    lock inc DWORD PTR [eax]
    ret
SemaphoreSignal ENDP
```